# jbdc ignores aliases in sql statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sybase

In my java app I running sql query for example:

```
select rowid as col1, id as col2 from dummy_table
```

and then, when I use ResultSetMetaData.getColumnNames I expect to get column aliases (col1 and col2), but method returns physical column names.

So, my question is, how to get column aliases using ResultSetMetaData

I use Java 1.6, Jdbc, Sybase

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use temporary tables,

```
   select rowid as col1, id as col2 INTO #tmp from dummy_table


    select * from #tmp
```

I think this will work.

For second solution 
also check  `String getColumnLabel(int column)` function of ResultSetMetaData

Comment: I think that it is not a good solution.
You will add additional io and potentially bad performance. Look at Mark Bannister answer.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe your driver doesn't understand aliased column. Try to invoke `ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel()` to see what it  get

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed something similar in MySQL - there, a quick fix is to turn your main query into a sub query, like so:

```
select v.* from (
select rowid as col1, id as col2 from dummy_table
) as v
```